# Use x509 cert to connect to a service

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I am trying to connect to MongoDB using X509 certificates from an EC2 instance. I initially stored .pem file for cert on EC2 instance and was able to connect directly using that:

```
mongo --tls --tlsCertificateKeyFile mycert.pem --tlsCAFile password  --authenticationDatabase '$external' --authenticationMechanism MONGODB-X509
```

Now I am trying to secure the key so it is not stored inside EC2 instance. I know I cannot use ACM for this purpose. So I saved mycert.pem on IAM, but I am not sure how to use it. I can get the cert:

```
aws iam get-server-certificate mycert
```

But how can I use mycert to connect to Mongo in above scenario?

Comment: I think you would have to save the certificate you receive from the IAM service to a local file, and then pass it via `--tlsCertificateKeyFile`. You would want to make sure the storage location in the EC2 instance is an EBS volume with encryption enabled, and you probably want to delete the certificate file as soon as the `mongo` command is finished.

Comment: @MarkB I was able to save the key, but IAM doesn't allow to retrieve the private key. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You should probably look into storing the key file in AWS SecretsManager instead of IAM.

Answer (score 2):

> Now I am trying to secure the key so it is not stored inside EC2 instance.

The key *must be* stored inside the instance, since the instance must use it.

You can store it in memory by creating a tmpfs partition and writing it to that partition as a file.

Answer (score 0):

Followed Mark B's direction and used AWS SecretsManager instead of IAM for saving X509 cert.